# javascript change image onclick

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change a part of a photo? I do not know how to do this - when I click on the white ball part of the lamp changes. For now I did something like that http://mantykora.cleoni.com/~newsletter/2017/gabi/2017_Gabi_2.html

```
<script>
function pictureChange()
{
document.getElementById("theImage").src="gold.jpg";
}


function pictureChange2()
{
document.getElementById("theImage").src="miedz.jpg";
}


function pictureChange3()
{
document.getElementById("theImage").src="stal.jpg";
}

function pictureChange4()
{
document.getElementById("theImage").src="816_Gabi_white.png";
}
</script>

<td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" onClick="pictureChange()"><img src="816_Gabi_kolory_GOLD.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=""/></a></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" onClick="pictureChange2()"><img src="816_Gabi_kolory_MIEDZ.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=""/></a></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" onClick="pictureChange3()"><img src="816_Gabi_kolory_STAL.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=""/></a></td>
```

[image]

**UPDATE 1 - 2017-06-28**

I have made separate photos but I do not know how to connect Fabric.js plugin with javascript onclick - http://mantykora.cleoni.com/~newsletter/2017/gabi/html/index_2.html#

Comment: Your ID `theImage` does not correspond to a HTML Image DOM element.

Comment: Is some example how to do it properly?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb

Comment: Please post solutions as answers rather than updating the question. This is to help future visitors understand and to cause less confusion. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fabric.js plugin for updating the partly image. Here are the steps that you need to do for updating partly images

1. Add Fabric.js plugin
2. Create Canvas using fabric method. Refer this doc for same
   http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#canvas
3. Add Top Image And Bottom image same as added below sample images.
   Refer http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#images
4. Once user click on Color spear you need to update the images
   according to the selected object.

Here are the Demo Links for your references

http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1#images

[image: TopImage]
[image]

I have updated code below. I have added updateImage function for updating image while click on images . Just you need to pass image

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('c');
 
 fabric.Image.fromURL('Gold_001A.png', function(img) {

    canvas.add(img.set({ left: 35, top: 50, angle: 0, id:'theImage2' }).scale(1));
  });
  
  fabric.Image.fromURL('Gold_001B.png', function(img) {
    canvas.add(img.set({ left: 35, top: 50, angle: 0, id:'theImage' }).scale(1));
  });
  
/* Funtion for updating image 
@param {string}{imageName} Image name or image url for loading and updating
*/
function updateImage(imageName){
 fabric.Image.fromURL(imageName, function(img) {
  var object= getImageObjectUsingId('theImage');
    canvas.remove(object);
  canvas.add(img.set({ left: 35, top: 50, angle: 0, id:'theImage' }).scale(1));
  });

}

/* Function for getting perticular object for updating the images
@param {String}{id} Object Id for selecting object . Same as use while creating object
*/
function getImageObjectUsingId(id){
 var listOfObjects= canvas.getObjects();
 for(var i=0; i< listOfObjects.length; i++){
  if(listOfObjects[i].id==id){
   return listOfObjects[i];
  }
 }

}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle"><table width="600" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><canvas id="c" width="800" height="800" class="lower-canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;"></canvas>
</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"><table width="600" border="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                <!--update image for updating image using updateImage function and pass iamge name or url in that funtion-->
                  <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" onclick="updateImage('816_Gabi_white.png')"><img src="./Dokument bez tytułu_files/816_Gabi_kolory_GOLD.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=""></a></td>
                  <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" onclick="updateImage('816_Gabi_kolory_MIEDZ.jpg')"><img src="./Dokument bez tytułu_files/816_Gabi_kolory_MIEDZ.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=""></a></td>
                  <td align="center" valign="middle"><img src="./Dokument bez tytułu_files/816_Gabi_kolory_STAL.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt=""></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I did so http://mantykora.cleoni.com/~newsletter/2017/gabi/html/index_2.html# But now the links do not work, I do not know where to insert it id="theImage

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Everything works so far. Now I just have to render white and silver track in 3dsMax. Result http://mantykora.cleoni.com/~newsletter/2017/gabi/html/index_2A.html#